# Are there any mechanisms other than copy elision that can optimize out excessive construction in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-optimization

My function has a switch-case statement. There is an object that is used only in some of its branches. Can I put an initialization of this object before the switch-case statement and expect that it will be created only when it is actually being used.

By that, I mean, is there any difference in performance between this code:

```
void someFunc( SomeEnum someEnum, Parameter parameter )
{
    Object object( parameter );
    
    switch( someEnum )
    {
    case SomeEnum::A:
        otherFunc( object );
        break;
        
    case SomeEnum::B:
        otherFunc( object );
        break;
        
    case SomeEnum::C:
        anotherFunc();
        break;
    }
}
```

And this one:

```
void someFunc( SomeEnum someEnum, Parameter parameter )
{   
    switch( someEnum )
    {
    case SomeEnum::A: {
            Object object( parameter );
            otherFunc( object );
        }
        break;
        
    case SomeEnum::B: {
            Object object( parameter );
            otherFunc( object );
        }
        break;
        
    case SomeEnum::C:
        anotherFunc();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: as-if rule... but then `Object object( parameter)` should not have side effect.

Comment: have you determined this is a bottleneck?

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry, overlooked this part. Fixed.

Comment: @bolov yes, pretty much. I haven't done benchmarks, but this is going to be a reoccurring pattern in a bunch of very frequently executed methods.

Comment: @Forthleft: "*yes, pretty much. I haven't done benchmarks*" Then you haven't *determined* it is a bottleneck; you are *presuming* that it *might* be one.

Comment: @NicolBolas You don't always need the numbers to understand how something will affect the performance. I understand the concept of premature optimizations, but this is not the case, if you are implying it. I mean, you don't really need benchmarks to be pretty confident that allocating memory on the heap hundreds of thousands of times per second isn't acceptable in a realtime app. I'm not presuming, I'm _sure_, that this _will_ be a bottleneck.

Comment: @Forthleft: Then you're focused on solving the wrong problem. The problem is not that this object might have its constructor invoked when it's not strictly necessary. The problem is that the constructor *is too expensive* to invoke the number of times it may be invoked. Turn the expensive heap allocation into a cheap arena or pool allocator. Or remove the expensive object entirely and solve the problem in a different way. Hot loop should not be doing heap allocations *at all*, even conditionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I put an initialization of this object before the switch-case statement and expect that it will be created only when it is actually being used.

No. There is no mechanism in the C++ standard that will permit an object which is stated in the text to be created to only *actually* be created based on runtime information.

Now, if `Object` is trivial, or if the compiler can see that `Object`'s constructor/destructor have no visible side effects outside of manipulating the state of that object, then a compiler could under the "as-if" rule effectively convert your first code into the second code. But this is only because nothing can check to see if the object was or was not created.

Note that "visible side effects" include things like calling memory allocation functions, opening files, or other OS-level heavyweight activities. IE: precisely the kinds of things that you would probably be specifically concerned about from a performance standpoint. So if this actually is going to matter for performance, then odds are good that compilers won't be able to "as-if" it away.

So if you have an explicit *need* to delay construction, you should be explicit about it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on both the compiler and `Object`. In the former example, a bad compiler like msvc is actually going to allocate *less* stack space, and in the latter N times as much stack space. But if the constructor of `Object` does some heavy work and/or dynamically allocates a lot of memory, then the latter would be preferrable, since the constructor only will be called if a  `case` is reached.

Comment: "a bad compiler like msvc" Umm... I get bashing on MSVC for lacking C conformance and lagging behind in the past on implementing new standard features, but even ignoring how far they've come now and how they are even spearheading some of C++ new features, calling it a "bad compiler" is too much. Do you have any sources for this?

Comment: I would cite its source code; but it is closed source so I can't. Furthermore I suggest you checkout my recent question here on SO. It's a live example of why compilers like clang should be preferred.

Comment: @Hi-IloveSO: I looked at that question, and it hasn't been established what the right answer even is in this case ("right" as in what the standard says should happen. I don't know enough about the complexities of templates to say what the standard says on the matter). Until someone weighs in as to what the correct behavior ought to be, that question is hardly evidence of any compiler being good or bad.

Comment: All the compilers have bug, pointing on one case where clang is right (and even that seems not an evidence) is not really relevant as other can also point to cases where only clang fails...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's because this example is over-simplified, but having that object is pretty much irrelevant to the operation of the code -- its value is never used. So instead of a named variable that doesn't have any significant use, create a temporary:

```
otherFunc(Object());
```

Of course, this won't work if `otherFunc` expects to be able to modify its argument.

Another possibility (again, assuming that `otherFunc` doesn't modify its argument) is to use a default argument:

```
void otherFunc(Object object = Object());
```

Now you can call it without an explicit argument:

```
otherFunc();
```

and the compiled code will generate a temporary at the point of the call.